# Can a device create/guide neuron connections between them?

Tags: neuroscience, eeg, neurophysiology

Is there a device of some sort that could promote/guide/create exact connections between neurons? I wish there was a device that could get me PhD by just wearing it for a few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a PhD using an electronic device, that's the stuff for movies (Fig. 1). Plus, as I claim in [my profile](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/users/6983/aliced?tab=profile), there's a lot more to science than learning new material:

> Behind the great achievements of a Gauss or an Einstein is in all
>   cases a life devoted to contemplation, curiosity, collaboration and,
>   perhaps most of all, hard work [(Burrell, 2015)](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-quest-for-genius-in-einstein-s-brain/).

However, to bring your question down to a more elementary level, there are concepts in development to guide neuronal growth toward certain targets, for example for use in [cochlear implants](https://advancedbionics.com/com/en/home/about-cochlear-implants/what-is-a-cochlear-implant-system.html) (CIs). CIs stimulate the inner ear in people with severe hearing impairment. A CI basically consists of an array of electrodes that is guided into the inner ear. Because the electrode contacts are situated relatively far from the target neurons (spiral ganglion cells making up the auditory nerve, see Fig. 2), scientists have been contemplating how to bring the source closer to the target. One way to (theoretically) do this is to coat the electrode array with a solution releasing neurotrophic factor(s), such as BDNF(*e.g.*, [Ramku *et al*. (2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5420760/)). These compounds are known to act as chemo-attractants that can stimulate and guide neural outgrowths.

[image: Matrix]
<sup>Fig. 1. Reaves learning Kunf Fu. source: [EJ4](https://www.ej4.com/blog/3-out-of-5-trainers-are-not-morpheus)</sup>

[image: CI]
<sup>Fig. 2. CI. source: [Debener (2016)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312383271_Cortical_plasticity_in_cochlear_implant_users/figures?lo=1)</sup>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Burrell, *Sci Am*, September issue 2015](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-quest-for-genius-in-einstein-s-brain/)

**-** [Debener, Cortical plasticity in cochlear implant users (2016). Thesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312383271_Cortical_plasticity_in_cochlear_implant_users/figures?lo=1)

**-** [Ramku *et al*., *Open Access Maced J Med Sci* (2017); **5**(2): 121–5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5420760/)</sub>

Comment: ok if growing new neurons is out of question for now. Then what about creating a computer that simulate neurons and attach that to brain. For example in this study part of brain of a mouse is connected to another mouse over internet, and one mouse is demonstrates knowledge that was taught only to other mouse. https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/feb/28/brains-rats-connected-share-information

Comment: oh instead of electrodes we could have nanobots, but i know we dont have that yet.